# Quiero traer en la definición de un src="" de html el resultado de una variable de un archivo de javascript

Tags: javascript

El inconveniente es el siguiente
Aquí en el html creo el formulario y mando el resultado en la variable parturarp()

```
<label class="col-3" for="CDPenitencial">Penitencial</label>


                  <select class="col-7" id="Penitencial">
                    <option value="Cantos/PE0001.html" selected>Señor ten Piedad</option>
                    <option value="Cantos/PE0002.html">Alabaré</option>
                  </select>
                  <button type="button" class="col-1" onclick="capturarp()">Capturar</button>
```

Ahora en Javascript recojo la opción seleccionada en la variable parturarp y en consola la trae sin problema, el .js es

```
function capturarp(){

    var Penitencialform = document.getElementById("Penitencial").value;

    console.log(Penitencialform);
}
```

Ahora lo que necesito, en OTRA HOJA DE html, es traer el resultado de esa variable y que sea reemplazada por el valor del src del iframe

```
<section id="penitencial" class="penitencial">
    <h1 class="container">Penitencial</h1>
    <iframe src="**Cantos/EN0003.html**" class="encuentro"></iframe>
</section>
```

Es decir que en lugar de Cantos/EN0003.html me reemplace por el valor de la variable anterior.
Como lo puedo solucionar?.
Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para ir conociendo el sitio. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con [**`localstorage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). En tu función `capturarp()` puedes almacenar el valor en `localstorage` de la siguiente forma:

```
function capturarp() {
  var Penitencialform = document.getElementById("Penitencial").value;
  console.log(Penitencialform);
  localStorage.setItem('penitencialSeleccionado', Penitencialform);
}
```

Y en tu otra vista, ya que tienes esto:

```
<section id="penitencial" class="penitencial">
  <h1 class="container">Penitencial</h1>
  <iframe src="**Cantos/EN0003.html**" class="encuentro"></iframe>
</section>
```

Podemos indicar que cuando cargue la página, asignamos el valor almacenado del `localstorage` al `src` de tu `iframe`, así:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let penitencialSeleccionado = localStorage.getItem('penitencialSeleccionado');
  let iframe = document.querySelector("#penitencial iframe");
  iframe.src = penitencialSeleccionado;
});
```

Y en el caso de que no encuentre ningún valor, es mejor condicionarlo con un `if` y así no asignar un valor vacío o nulo:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let penitencialSeleccionado = localStorage.getItem('penitencialSeleccionado');
  let iframe = document.querySelector("#penitencial iframe");
  if (penitencialSeleccionado)
    iframe.src = penitencialSeleccionado;
});
```

Comment: Estoy comenzando en esto ya que sigue sin funcionar.

Pegue la función descrita así toda seguida en el archivo de javascript así.

function capturarp() {
  var Penitencialform = document.getElementById("penitencial").value;
  console.log(Penitencialform);
  localStorage.setItem('penitencialSeleccionado', Penitencialform);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let penitencialSeleccionado = localStorage.getItem('penitencialSeleccionado');
  let iframe = document.querySelector("#penitencial iframe");
  iframe.src = penitencialSeleccionado;
 });

Comment: buen día, ¿Qué nuevo error estas obteniendo?...

Comment: Cris, en la pagina donde debería verse el iframe, me sale en blanco, no sé si no está tomando el valor.

Comment: ¿Colocaste el tercer fragmento de código en tu otra página? Ese código indica que cuando carga la página, va a buscar el valor del `localStorage` y lo asignará al `src` de tu `iframe`... En todo caso inspecciona elemento, ve a *Application*, luego a *localStorage* y verifica si ahí está tu valor almacenado.

Comment: Gracias Cris, creo que ya me funcionó. Dios te bendiga.

Comment: Buenos Días. Cris tengo una pregunta, ya me funcionó perfecto pero solo en mi dispositivo, es decir, yo ya tengo la pagina en un host gratuito y entro desde otro celular o tablet y quiero ver si están aplicando los cambios veo que sólo lo está tomando desde el mismo celular, como hago para que el canto que yo seleccione se vea modificado en todos los dispositivos, imagino que es el por el localstorage. Gracias.

Comment: Mmm podrías hacerlo con base de datos, en este caso...

Comment: Cristian que pena una pregunta. lo puedo crear con indexedDB?

Comment: Claro, con cualquier base de datos.